# Error: Table 's' was not locked with LOCK TABLES at $table->store()

Tags: jtable

I'm trying to load an existing table (not using primary key) and then storing it, but get this error:

> Error: Table 's' was not locked with LOCK TABLES: Unknown column 'alias' in 'field list'

My code:

```
$module = JTable::getInstance('Module');
$module->load(['title' => $title]);
// ... set properties, or not, same error anyway
$module->store(true);
```

Any ideas?

I'm using MySQL 8.

Comment: `load()` is explicitly designed to receive a primary key. https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Table.Table.html#method_load  But https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class says "Method to load into the JTable object a record by its primary key value (id) **or a combination of criteria**".  This post suggests that a primary key or composite primary keys are expected: https://groups.google.com/g/joomla-dev-general/c/lkaZpkZdfSE/m/otNYg2nSsTEJ?pli=1

Comment: @mickmackusa OK, so I can't use JTable when loading by other criteria?

Comment: Better not take my word for it.  Wait for somebody smarter than me to chime in.

Comment: @mickmackusa Hehe, thanks. I might as well rewrite the code using stdClass and saveObject, it's fine too.